# Angular 4 how to animate scroll dynamically

Tags: angular

I have a component with a few divs , each one with ID.

On change of the fragment the page scroll to the div with the matching ID.

What I am trying to do is to scroll with animation instead of just 'jumping' to the place.

What I am having troubles with is to do it dynamic, meaning, scroll according to where the page is now and how far the new fragment is.

Component:

```
@Component({
   selector:'parent',
   template:`
     <div [@fragmentChanged]="fragment">
       <div id="part1">
        ........
       </div>
       <div id="part2">
        ........
       </div>
       <div id="part3">
       ........
       </div>
     </div>
    `,
   animations:[
     trigger:('fragmentChanged',[
        transition('* => *',[
            animate:(2000,style({transform:'translateY(???)'}))
         ])
      ])
   ]
})
export class ParentComponent{

    fragment:string;

    constractor(private route:ActivatedRoute){
    }

    ngOnInit(){
       this.route.fragment.subscribe( (fragment) => {
           this.fragment = fragment;
           this.scrollToFragment();
    })

    scrollToFragment(){
        try{
            if(document.querySelector('#' + this.fragment)){
               document.querySelector('#' + this.fragment).scrollIntoView();
            }
        } catch (e) {
          console.log(e)
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code, what I am actually missing is how to calculate dynamically the parameter to send to the 'TranslateY' and if it is minus or plus (scroll up or down...)

Any ideas / help?

Comment: Have you tried e.g. http://iamdustan.com/smoothscroll/, rather than an Angular animation?

Comment: you are right, there was no need for angular animation, works now great with this library, thanks!